# how to copy the files and folders before a particular date from one server to another in linux

Tags: centos

Please help me with the exact command to do this operation.
I've tried this format
find /home/sharath/ -mtime 365 -exec scp "{}" root@foreignhost:/home/sharath/

but Iam unable to copy all the files which are more than 1yr back all files.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should to use `find /home/sharath/ -mtime +365 -exec scp "{}" root@foreignhost:/home/sharath/ \;`.